# How do i make buttons generated with php work?

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic

Btn1 fires the getId function appropriately but the other two btns do not, how can i make them work correctly? 
I think the code below shows what i am trying to achieve so please ignore the rest of this paragraph. This is here because the page will not allow me to post the question until i add more details.

```
<?php 
    $id ="22";
    $name = "Joseph";
    $btn1 = "<button onclick='getId($id)'>$name $id</button>";
    $btn2 = "<button onclick='getId($id,$name)'>$name $id</button>";    
    $btn3 = "<button onclick='getId($name)'>$name $id</button>";

    echo $btn1;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $btn2; 
    echo "<br>";
    echo $btn3; 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
    function getId(x, y) {  
        alert(x);
        alert(y)
        console.log(x);
        console.log(y);
    }
</script>
<body>
    "ReferenceError: Joseph is not defined"
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you are passing strings into the function as a parameterit needs to be within quotes. ie: `"<button onclick='getId(1,\"bob\")'>$name $id</button>";` or `"<button onclick='getId($id,\"$name\")'>$name $id</button>"; `

Answer (score 1):

With regards to passing strings as parameters to a function ( as above ) the string value needs to be quoted otherwise you will get an error. Rather than hardcoding the parameters in this instance what you could do would be to use the `arguments` object inherent to functions and access the parameters dynamically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>function arguments and quotes....</title>
    </head>
    <script>
        function getId() {  
            for( let i=0; i < arguments.length;i++ ){
                alert(arguments[i]);
                console.info(arguments[i]);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <?php 

            $id ="22";
            $name = "Joseph";
            $btn1 = "<button onclick='getId($id)'>$name $id</button>";
            $btn2 = "<button onclick='getId($id,\"$name\")'>$name $id</button>";    
            $btn3 = "<button onclick='getId(\"$name\")'>$name $id</button>";

            echo $btn1;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $btn2; 
            echo "<br>";
            echo $btn3; 
        ?>  
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
function getId() {  
  for( let i=0; i < arguments.length;i++ ){
    alert(arguments[i]);
    console.info(arguments[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick='getId(22)'>Joseph 22</button><br>
<button onclick='getId(22,"Joseph")'>Joseph 22</button><br>
<button onclick='getId("Joseph")'>Joseph 22</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $id ="22";
    $name = "Joseph";
    $btn1 = "<button onclick='getId($id,\"$name\")'>$name $id</button>";

    echo $btn1;
    echo "<br>";    
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
    function getId(x, y) {  
        alert(x);
        alert(y)
        console.log(x);
        console.log(y);
    }
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```